# How to flatten a Tensorflow PolicyStep, TimeStep, and Trajectory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, tensor

So I'm trying to build my first Q learning neural network using Tensorflow. My PolicyStep and TimeStep are generated from Tensorflow policy.action and env.step however they have one more extra dimension. But the the agent.train requires a flatten version of the time step and action step. I'm not sure why this is happening given that the same environment is used in my agent and trajectory collection function.

```
loss = agent.train(experience=traj).loss

ValueError: All of the Tensors in `value` must have two outer dimensions. Specifically, tensors must have shape `[B, T] + spec.shape`.
Full shapes of value tensors:
  Trajectory(
{'action': TensorShape([1]),
 'discount': TensorShape([1]),
 'next_step_type': TensorShape([1]),
 'observation': TensorShape([1, 54]),
 'policy_info': (),
 'reward': TensorShape([1]),
 'step_type': TensorShape([1])}).
Expected shapes (excluding the two outer dimensions):
  Trajectory(
{'action': TensorShape([]),
 'discount': TensorShape([]),
 'next_step_type': TensorShape([]),
 'observation': TensorShape([54]),
 'policy_info': (),
 'reward': TensorShape([]),
 'step_type': TensorShape([])}).
```

How would I flatten my trajectory information so that the extra dimension goes away?

Comment: Got it to work by shifting to reverb instead of manually implementing the collect_step method.

Answer (score 0):

Got it to work by shifting to reverb instead of manually implementing the collect_step method.